# How to share multiple files with react-native-share

Tags: react-redux, shared-libraries, react-native, file-sharing

I was working on my project and what I need is to implement a way to send multiple files through react-native-share or with any other module

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    const pathUrl = "file://"+this.state.pdfInfo[0].path
    Share.open({
      url: [pathUrl, pathUrl]
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }}
  style={{marginRight:20}}
>
  <Icon name="md-share-social" size={25} color="black"/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

When user press this Icon it should share the multiple files with in array. But, since react-native-share expects string for it so, how we can go for it???

Is there any other way to do it??

Comment: Do you try to replace `url` to `urls` ?

Comment: checkout single or multiple images sharing answer by me with more info here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016851/want-to-share-multiple-images-with-separate-caption-to-each-image-whatsapp-reac/67167916#67167916

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `url` with `urls`

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    const pathUrl = "file://"+this.state.pdfInfo[0].path
    Share.open({
      urls: [pathUrl, pathUrl]
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }}
  style={{marginRight:20}}
>
  <Icon name="md-share-social" size={25} color="black"/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```